# How to use ons-navigator with React.js

Tags: onsen-ui

I want to use [Onsen UI 2.0](https://onsen.io/2/) with React.

In Onsen UI 2.0's [reference](https://onsen.io/2/reference/ons-navigator.html), `var` which is Attributes of `ons-navigator` is used to refer navigator.

But, `var` can be used with only Angular. So my question is how to refer navigator with React.

Comment: I don't know too much about React, but in OnsenUI 2.0 components are HTML elements so you can get them with `document.querySelector(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I tried it and it work well.

Answer (score 2):

to access elements in React use ref https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html.

That being said, unfortunately Onsen 2.0 is still in the beta and does not work well with ons-navigator, yet. Hopefully in later versions it will, you can follow https://onsen.io/blog/ for updates.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried it, but it have not been worked well as you say.
I will check on your reference.

Comment: i will try to remember to comment here, ones it is fully working, or partially.

Comment: @c8112002 The react components are in the beta phase right now: https://github.com/OnsenUI/react-onsenui.